# How to convert only second and third byte from byte array to integer number ( second is least significant than third)?

Tags: python-2.7

I receive from socket byte array. How to convert only second and third byte to integer number ( second is least significant than third) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed what you are asking, but do you mean like this?

```
b = bytearray("123456789")
b[1]
# 50
b[2]
# 51

int(chr(b[1]))
# 2
int(chr(b[2]))
# 3
```